# Understanding flow of execution in a program

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm creating a stopwatch that stops after hearing a clap. My first function with the stopwatch object should call the second function, `draw`, and should stay in that function, continually listening until  `vol > 0.3`. Then, it should return and stop my stopwatch. However, while the volume seems to register, my function never returns and stops the stopwatch. What part of the flow of execution am I not understanding? How can I make my first function stop the stopwatch once the volume hits the threshold in my draw function?

```
function callStopwatch() {
    var watch = new Stopwatch(timer);
    watch.start();
    if(draw()){
        watch.stop();
    }
}

function draw() {
    let flag = false;
    var vol = mic.getLevel();
    if(vol > 0.2){
        console.log("true"); //created to check whether sound detection is working
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems with your code:

1. You shouldn't call `draw()` from other functions. P5.js automatically calls the `draw()` function for you 60 times per second. You shouldn't call it yourself.
2. You shouldn't return anything from the `draw()` function. Because `draw()` is called automatically and not by you, the return value is simply ignored.
3. You're never calling your `callStopwatch()` function anyway.

I think you probably want to refactor your code. Use the P5.js flow to your advantage. Specifically, P5.js calls the `setup()` function at the beginning of your sketch, and it calls `draw()` 60 times per second. Use that structure to structure your logic.

Here's a skeleton of how I would approach it:

```
var stopwatch;

function setup(){
  stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); 
  stopwatch.start();
}

function draw(){
  var vol = mic.getLevel();
  if(vol > 0.2){
    stopwatch.stop();
  }
}
```